# Google Chrome always asks to unlock keyring after login

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, cinnamon

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I think my one is not the same.

After logging in, google chrome asks me to open the `Login` keyring. Then, I typed the password and checked the box not to ask it again. But after new loging in, Chrome asked it again and it created a new keyring. I didn't have this problem a week ago. Does anyone know the hint to fix this problem?

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Cinnamon 3.8.9

[image]

Comment: May be will work, may be not. Delete keyring Login. Create keyring Login with same password as Ubuntu login. That's helped me once.

Comment: I've already tried it, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files in `~/.local/share/keyrings` fixed the problem.